# Issues proxying POST APIs with bodies on Windows / .Net

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I'm putting together a Proof of Concept for WSO2, and can proxy a local spring boot service (on mac) that sends in a JSON object in the POST body with no issues.  However, when I try to deploy WSO2 on a windows machine, proxying a .Net service running locally, I get NullReference errors, as the body is not being passed through.  I can hit the same service via Postman directly, no problems.  Change the endpoint to the WSO2 AM proxy, failure.  Is there something I'm missing to why it behaves differently when running on Windows or against a .Net service?

API Manager version: 1.9.0
I'm happy to provide additional information as needed - Thanks!

Update - adding stack trace per comment request:
I can't post full stack trace due to confidentiality, but from inside the .net service:

```
 System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
     HResult=-2147467261
      Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I'm logging the inflow AND outflow from the AM publisher console, and am seeing the data (albeit in XML, not JSON), and the .net generated error response .

Comment: forgot to explicitly mention - on a GET request with params it works just fine - just on POST with a body parameter.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace you come across. It can help isolate the issue.

Comment: I did notice that I was using java 1.8, so tried downgrading to 1.7 per message that 1.8 is not supported - same result